# automagic versus form-element specific

Tags: php, cakephp

Whats the difference between automagic form elements versus form-element specific methods? Is it only because automagic automatically creates a div & label?

Comment: I am hearing automatic form elements for the first time

Comment: The first paragraph says it all about the advantages of the FormHelper. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: he is probably talking about input() vs date(), number() etc

Answer (score 1):

the automagic `input()` reads the model to display the correct input type (i.e. if the database field is a date, it will display 3 selects)

It will also read the $this->data variable in the controller to fill the values of the inputs. And ,like you said, it will also create the divs, labels and errors for the form

In the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#generating-specific-types-of-inputs) it says:

> In addition to the generic input() method, FormHelper has specific
>   methods for generating a number of different types of inputs. These
>   can be used to generate just the input widget itself, and combined
>   with other methods like label() and error() to generate **fully custom**
>   form layouts.

Internally, `input()` uses the "non-automagic" methods like `text()`, `radio()`, etc.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: which method is the best to use? Or is it just a matter of preference?